# "brain dead" links

Tags: html

```
    <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/">Visit W3Schools</a>
```

Here's a link.

I insert it into a given DIV, it's displayed perfectly as expected and where expected, however, the cursor doesn't change into a link and clicking this doesn't do anything.

I insert this into a different div, it's displayed perfectly and works perfectly.

Can anything be done in CSS to prevent links from working? what could be different between those DIVs?

It's a mystery. This behavior is consistent across Chrome, FF, IE and Safari

Comment: can you give an example in jsfiddle? or can you post the html and css?

Comment: The html and CSS are miles long. I was just asking if there's a known way to "zap" links from working via CSS, as CSS is the only difference between the two DIV's. they are sibling DIVS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS can’t disable a link. Something’s probably overlapping it. Right click and choose `Inspect Element` to see what it is.

Comment: that's probably it. my initial div was located outside of the main content div, I guess the CSS structure must have caused some overlap on hit-testing. Moving it inside it resolved the problem immediately.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance there is a `div` positioned over top of it.

Add the following styles to the link to confirm:

`<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/" style="display:block; z-index:1000;">Visit W3Schools</a>`